# Custom post type tag archives don't work for basic loop?

Tags: custom-post-types, tags, archives

I have registered a custom post type with the right parameters. By that I mean I have added `'taxonomies' => array('post_tag','category')`,

I have also tried using `register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'custom-post-type-name');`

I have a custom function in my functions.php to load a basic loop using a conditional, along the lines of.

```
function child_maybe_do_grid_loop() {    
if( is_tag() || is_category() || is_archive {
require(CHILD_DIR.'/custom-tag.php');
 }
}
```

The content of custom-tag.php is just a very basic loop

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
 <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
   <?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?> 
 <?php endwhile; ?>    
<?php else : ?>
<h2 class="center">Not Found</h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This works fine for regular posts/page tags but for a custom post type tags I get "Not Found".

Any ideas? I assumed a regular simple loop should work with custom posts type tag archives or do I need to put some extra conditionals/query's in there?

** Update toscho's comment made me turn on debugging and in comparison to a working tag page made through a default post, the debug for custom post tag is exactly the same.

I even get count => 2 to show up as I incrementally add more custom posts to the same tag, yet the page refuses to return anything,  I am at a loss.

Comment: Do yout get nothing or the Not Found message? Do you have refreshed your permalinks after registration?

Comment: Actually I do get the "not found", I have refreshed the permalinks, cleared cache, and the tags are showing up for my custom post type in the admin. I should be clear that my conditional statement is in functions.php that loads the basic loop which is in a separate file.

Comment: I had a [similar problem](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12611/page-queried-instead-of-a-custom-taxonomy) recently. The rewrite rules were not applied and I had to add them manually. Did you check this?

Comment: Thanks,  will do tomorrow getting late here. I should also add this is for a site using the genesis template so I will debug and let you know.

Comment: What's the URL when you're viewing this problem tag archvie? .. Most queries will use a default post type, typically that's post, try explicitly setting the post type parameter for the query.

Comment: The url is .com/tag/watermelon/ which works fine for post/pages but custom post type .com/tag/whatever  , I get not found, the "not found" tells me it's using the right template page. Also If I add it to an existing working tag, the custom post type does not show up, it is only populated by "default" posts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Down the rabbit hole.....  I found a fix.

From this post [Custom Post Type Archives by Date and Taxonomy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1878/custom-post-type-archives-by-date-and-taxonomy)

Which let me to this trac ticket http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14589

and the following

```
function post_type_tags_fix($request) {
    if ( isset($request['tag']) && !isset($request['post_type']) )
    $request['post_type'] = 'any';
    return $request;
} 
add_filter('request', 'post_type_tags_fix');
```

Maybe this didn't make it into 3.1?

Comment: Just FYI I had to do this on 3.8. My custom post types are using the default post_tag.

Comment: Same here, using 3.9.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the loop before the conditional statement.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

<?php if( is_tag() || is_category() || is_archive { ?>

<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?> 

<? } else { ?>

//do something else

} ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>    
<?php else : ?>
<h2 class="center">Not Found</h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I'm sorry my questions was worded poorly I'll fix it.